# printing the max of an array- Java

Tags: arrays

*Write a piece of code that examines an array of integers and reports the maximum value in the array to `System.out`. Consider putting your code into a method called max that accepts the array as a parameter and returns the maximum value. Assume that the array contains at least one element. Your method should not modify the elements of the array.*

This is what i have:

```
public int max(int []a)
{
int maxVal=0;
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>maxVal)
            {
                maxVal=a[i];
            }
        }
        return maxVal;
    }
```

Problem is that it doesnt work for the values of `max({-4, -5, -3, -6})`.

How can i fix this to work for that test as well as all others?

Comment: The problem with your setup is you initialize maxVal=0 so none of those values are larger, therefore reporting an incorrect answer. You should initialize maxVal=a[0]. See Vivi-T's answer.

Comment: We're not here to answer homework questions, asking a community such as This one won't help with your learning.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int max(int []a)
 { 
int maxVal=a[0];
 for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 { 
if(a[i]>maxVal) 
{
 maxVal=a[i];
 }
 } return maxVal;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another more helpful way;

> import java.util.Arrays;

sort your arrays by -

> > Arrays.sort(array);

then -

> > > int c = array.length;
> > >       System.out.println(array[c-1]);